# Align text and use indent 

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I want to align my text and also use indent at each paragraph.But it seems i can use only one of them (either alignment or indent).

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{flushleft}

\section {Heading}

\indent Here is text.....

\par\indent Another text,....

\end{flushleft}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want this?  `flushleft` uses `\raggedright` which sets `\parindent` to 0 if you `\setlength\parindent{2em}` after starting the environment you will get a visible indent again.

Comment: Ok, thanks , work great.But why are you saying if i am sure about that?Is there another way to have alignment with indent?

Comment: No, I meant that it's a rather unusual style to want. If you look at published works then I would guess that you won't see this often.